# Calculate hourly turnout with pandas and Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to find the number of times a certain value "PAY" appears in a hourly range column.

I have made the dataframe with pandas:

```
df = pd.read_json('test.json')
print(df.head(3))
print(df.dtypes)
```

```
  TransactionCode                           Date  
1             PAY  2021-12-09T10:23:29.242+01:00  
2             PAY  2021-12-09T10:23:02.978+01:00  
3             PAY  2021-12-09T10:22:48.659+01:00 

TransactionCode       object
Date                  object
```

After I split the column Date in two column, "Date" and "Time":

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.time
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
print(df.head())
print(df.dtypes)
```

```
  TransactionCode        Date             Time
1             PAY  2021-12-09  10:23:29.242000
2             PAY  2021-12-09  10:23:02.978000
3             PAY  2021-12-09  10:22:48.659000
4             PAY  2021-12-09  11:32:48.659000
5             PAY  2021-12-09  11:45:12.659000


TransactionCode       object
Date                  object
Time                  object
```

I wish to iterate over column "Time" to know for each day how many times appear the "PAY" value.
I need this to build a hourly turnout plot with Matplotlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the following dataframe:

```
    TransactionCode       Date             Time
1               PAY 2021-12-09  10:23:29.242000
2               PAY 2021-12-09  10:23:02.978000
3               PAY 2021-12-09  10:22:48.659000
4               ERR 2021-12-09  11:32:48.659000
5               PAY 2021-12-09  11:45:12.659000
```

You could do this:

```
df['Hour'] = [time.hour for time in df['Time']]
df[df['TransactionCode'] == 'PAY'][['TransactionCode','Hour']].groupby('Hour').count().plot(kind='bar');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could convert to datetime, `set_index` on Date and `resample` to hours, finally plot:

```
df2 = (
 df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']))
   .set_index('Date')
   .loc[lambda d: d['TransactionCode'].eq('PAY')]
   .resample('1H').count()
)
```

output:

```
                           TransactionCode
Date                                      
2021-12-09 10:00:00+01:00                3
2021-12-09 11:00:00+01:00                2
```

Plot:

```
df2.plot.bar()
```

[image]